# Парсинг aspx страницы с помощью cURL php

Tags: php, post, curl, aspx

Есть проблема с парсингом aspx страницы. Пытаюсь получить информацию о доставке груза, проблема в том, что страница выводится, однако информация о доставке груза не отображается. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Вроде куки нормально отдаются (ид сессии и тд.), № заказа указан.

Код php ниже:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookieFileName");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://79.174.68.35/Client/Tracking.aspx");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ctl00  $ContentPlaceHolderMain$TextBoxNumbers=00000000316505");  

ob_start();  
curl_exec ($ch);  
ob_end_clean();  

curl_close ($ch);  
unset($ch);  

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookieFileName");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://79.174.68.35/Client/Tracking.aspx");  

echo $buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);  

curl_close ($ch);
```

Пробовал как ниже, но тогда ругается что проверка МАС не удалась:

Код php ниже:

```
$url = "http://79.174.68.35/Client/Tracking.aspx";    
$ckfile = tempnam("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");    
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US)  AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';

$f = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); // file to write request header for debug purpose

/**
    Get __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION
 */
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $viewstate);
preg_match('~<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="(.*?)" />~', $html, $eventValidation);

$viewstate = $viewstate[1];
$eventValidation = $eventValidation[1];


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

// Collecting all POST fields
$postfields = array();
$postfields['__LASTFOCUS']='';
$postfields['__EVENTTARGET'] = '';
$postfields['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = '';
$postfields['__VIEWSTATE'] = $viewstate;
$postfields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $eventValidation;
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$ButtonTracking'] = 'Проверить';
$postfields['ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$TextBoxNumbers'] = '00000000316505';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

print $ret;
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ctl00 $ContentPlaceHolderMain$TextBoxNumbers=00000000316505");` Имя POST-параметра формируется динамически из двух переменных?? Тут нет ошибки?

Comment: немного скорректировал вопрос, чтобы показать как пробовал еще